# Model binding not working for complex object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

### Introduction

I'm working an an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a pair of controller actions for submitting data and a corresponding view:

#### RequestsController.cs

```
public class RequestsController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ViewModel data)
    {
        return View(data);
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel.cs

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
}
```

#### Create.cshtml

```
@model Request

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors: true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Request</legend>

        @Html.EditorForModel()

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

### Problem

When the form is submitted with its fields populated, `Create(ViewModel)` is called with the `data` parameter set to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be that the framework didn't like the parameter in `Create` being named the same as the property of `ViewModel`. This can be worked around by renaming the parameter or the property.